# SSH—Can't reach iphone root folder

Tags: nautilus, ssh, iphone

When using Nautilus Connect to Server to connect with an iPhone over SSH, it takes me to a location that just has the Media and Library folders. Their location is

```
sftp://192.168.x.x/private/var/root/
```

How do you get to the /var or /private folders? Nautilus just shows the (192.168.x.x) button that takes you to sftp://192.168.x.x/private/var/root/.

Comment: What happens if you manually go to `sftp://192.168.x.x/var/`?

Comment: That works, but how do I do it in the nautilus GUI?

Comment: I think `Ctrl`+`L` should work to get a manual location bar. Or use the application menus to connect to a server and fill in all fields individually.

Comment: Yes that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> you'll see a textual/manual location bar appears in Nautilus file manager. Then edit the path yourself as you wish, e.g.

```
sftp://192.168.x.x/var/
```

I think it will go to `/private/var/root/` by default, because that is probably the home directory of the user on the remote end. The same thing happens when connecting to another host using SSH - your current working directory will be something like `/home/user`.